# Salesforce licenses

Tags: salesforce, force.com, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I'm struggling to get the best choice for me in terms of kind of license I need. I just want to connect my website using chatter through OAuth2 as well as I have been developing a canvas app. Everything has been done with my developer account in Salesforce but I have been wondering if I need to purchase any kind of salesforce license to use it. Even I have been wondering if I need a new license to upload my canvas app to salesforce appexchange.

I will be really grateful if someone could tell me something about it because I don't really know what I should do due to salesforce licenses are expensive.

Thank you so much

Diego

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would suggest you to do is create a Partnerforce account [here](https://sites.secure.force.com/partners/PP2PartnerLoginPage) if you are planning to sell your app on appexchange. After that, log a case on partnerforce asking them how to go about it. They are helpful people and should be able answer your questions well.

Answer (score 0):

To list the app on Salesforce you will have to follow certain steps:

1)  Firstly join the DeveloperForce free.

2)  Signup for Salesforce Partnership

3)  Now through APO Create a Test Org and select Partner Developer Org

4)  Through AppExchange you can easily publish your First app after packaging it.

5)  You will also have to go through Security Review before publishing the app. After the security review you can easily be able to view your package on AppExchange.

To get live on AppExchange just these steps are to be followed or you can also take the help of any experienced or existing Salesforce partner to get complete information abput listing your app on AppExchange. They can guide and help you throughout the procedure and to pass the Security review as well of Salesforce. A well known Salesforce partner is Janbask, who provide Salesforce implementation service and can provide you assistance and consultation as well. As they are Salesforce partner so know how to complete the process.

Apart from this you can try any Salesforce learning or training institute, if you are in your learning stage who can provide you complete detail and solution of your problem. You can easily [Integrate Salesforce](http://www.janbask.com/salesforce-integration/) and be able to view your app on AppExchange.